# Would it be a useful exercise for a data scientist to take Cryptography I on Coursera?

Tags: python, data-science-model

it seems to me that the python in Cryptography is similar to the Python of Neural Networks

Comment: I think a better exercise for a data scientist is to do more data science projects :) And it's not as if anybody could pretend that they know everything in data science, there is always something to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you're goal is to improve Python programing skills, there are many ways to do this. Cryptography on Coursera is probably not the best option for this. Some options; grind leetcode, read textbooks, read KDnuggets, build your project portfolio, take a bootcamp course, convert an existing R project to python, etc.

Comment: that's a very good and thoughtful answer!